# HERE maps en ionic no me muestra el mapa

Tags: angular, ionic

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Buenas comunidad, estoy teniendo un problema con el mapa de heremaps la implementarlo en ionic
no me muestra, he seguido el ejemplo de su documentación y con el código respectivo, luego instale el @types/heremaps tampoco y busque diversas soluciones y aun nada, incluso el setTimeout o talvez lo está haciendo mal, si me ayudan estaría agradecido, u otra alternativa de maps para ionic que no se google. Adjunto código

```html
declare var H: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-map',
  templateUrl: './map.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./map.page.scss'],
})
export class MapPage implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('myMap') mapDiv?: ElementRef;
  public map: any;

  private APIKEY: string = "";
  public firsPoint = false;
  public addresMap!: AddressMap;

  constructor(
    private _shared: SharedService,
    private modalCtrl: ModalController,
    private comunicacionService: ComunicacionService
  ) {
    this.APIKEY = environment.apiKeyMap;
    this.initInterface();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.initMap();
  }

  initMap(){
    this.initInterface();
    var platform = new H.service.Platform({
      apikey: this.APIKEY,
    });
    
    // Get the default map types from the Platform object:
    var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();
    
    // Instantiate the map:
    var map = new H.Map(
      document.getElementById("myMap"),
      //  map, type, layout
      defaultLayers.vector.normal.map, {
        zoom: 10,
        center: { lat: -0.22985, lng: -79 },
      }
    );
    

    // Create the default UI:
    var ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(map, defaultLayers);
    this.map = map;

    console.log(this.map);
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.map.getViewPort().resize();
    }, 500);
  }
}
```